# Quitar estilos al dar click en la X-- (Quitar este estilo estilSelectCateg )

Tags: jquery

Ya se pudo insertar div con jquery ahora pasamos a quitar estilos al dar click en la X  y no con el contenido completo

**Desde HTML**

```
  <div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
            <div id="categoria">                          
               include("selectCategJquery.php");
            <div class="mensCateg">Selecione las Categorias</div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**Desde selectCategJquery.php**

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>

<?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    $contador = 0;
    while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $contador++;
        $varHtml .='<div class="cont-optionElement">';
            $varHtml .= "<div id='elementoBusq' class='elemento ".$contador."' iden='".$contador."' >". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</div>";
        $varHtml .='</div>';
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

> ```
>   <script>
>
>       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>
>           $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
>              var e = $(this).clone();
>              var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");
>              var div = $('<div/>', {
>                               'class' : 'xClones',
>                               'html' : '<span>X</span>'
>
>                           });
>
>
>              if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
>                   $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).remove('');
>                   $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
>                  }else{
>                   $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
>                   $(e).append(div);
>                   $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").addClass("estilSelectCateg");
>              } 
>          });
>
>           $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
>              $(this).remove();
>           });
>           // $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
>           //   $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
>           // });
>
>
>       });
>   </script>
> ```

**Estilos CSS**

```
.xClones{
    top: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 3px;
    width: 25px;height: 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px hsla(12, 10%, 66%,1)inset;
}
```

**Imagen de Presentacion**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Son Dos detalles 1: Eliminar y 2: Quitar Estilos**
1:Eliminar de #campoBusq solo al dar en la X
2:Quitar estilos de seleccin de Caterias al dar click en la X
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Como vez el paso 2 se visualiza en la imagen, donde ?; justo en el estilo que de backround que no se removio al quitar el elemento de #campoBusq*
**Este es el Paso 1 que falta**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando l ances tu juego esperamos que nos menciones en los créditos

Comment: no es mala idea amigo jaja

Comment: Hola, Gamez XD! Apoyo el comentario de Amanadiel HAHAHAAH

Comment: este es un gran proyecto me fala demasiado, es mi primera pagina asi que no veo porque no darles credito; me han ahorrado mucho tiempo de trabajo para  solucionar solo un trosito de codigo

Comment: Y no entiendo tu pregunta por más que la leo. Más bien tu pregunta sí la entiendo pero no la descripción de lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: solo quiero  crear un div; al lado del div elemento, para que el usuario remueva de #campoBusq el contenido que selecciono; es decir asi; Reina al Maximo  [ X ], cuando la persona le de a la x se remueva ( Reina al Maximo de #campoBusq )

Comment: Pon el código html de #campoBusq que ya no me acuerdo cómo va, porfa

Comment: Si lo que quieres es crear un div pues deja te pongo el respuesta cómo le hagas, si necesitas más cosas me comentas ahí qué más falta

Comment: ok, te hare una imagen de un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear elementos puedes usar jQuery así:

```
var div = $('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'aquiLaClase',
    'id'    : 'unIdSiQuieres'
});
```

Puedes agrear los atributos que quieras. Si quieres el puro div pues basta con:

```
var div = $('<div/>');
```

Ahora, para agregarlo a otro div (en este caso creo que lo quieres agregar a #cont-optionElemen basta con hacerle un append.

```
$("#cont-optionElemen").append(div);
```

Comment: y en caso de asignarle contenido por ejemplo un texto al $div ?

Comment: Se utiliza el atributo "text"

Comment: O puedes crear contenido cualquiera y luego hacerle un append también a ese. div.append(contenidoQueQuieresAgregar);

Comment: voy a modificar el codigo ya hice algunas cosas pero ahora se presento otro detalle, ya lo especifico

Comment: Pero qué estilos quieres quitar o qué? Para quitar clases usas removeClass, para editar estilos de elementos usas .css()

Comment: ya te mando una imagen  cel problema

Comment: listo amigo ya solucione el paso 2 es asi : $("#categoria").find(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg"); solo falta que se elimine solo al dar en la X y no en el texto

Comment: hheehe ps sí, con removeClass como dije xd Y pues para que se elimine al dar solo en la X pues pásale el objeto de la equis, que según veo es el que tiene la clase X así: $(".x")on("click", function(){ $("#categoria").find(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("est‌​ilSelectCateg"); });

Comment: Ese no me funciona pero este si aunque me quita todoss los elementoss en vez de solo quiitar al que se le dio el click, este es el que tengo

Comment: $("#campoBusq").find(".elemento").remove();

Comment: Crees que hay posibilidad de asignar en este codigo un THIS para referenciar al elemento que se le dio el click y asi eliminar a ese solo

Comment: Por supuesto que sí.

Comment: como seria amigo, ese detalle lo ando buscando hace 3 dias

Comment: o si tienes una pagina mejor asi la estudio

Comment: Depende, si haces esto $(this).remove(); lo que quitarás es la equis xd, qué quieres quitar exactamente cuando le den a la equis?

Comment: aah quieres que se ejecute la función que te programé para quitar un elemento de un lado y ponerlo en otro?

Comment: si pero en este caso modificarlo solo con la X y no el texto que es(div:elemento)

Comment: Tiene que hacerlo con funciones que te traen el padre o el hermano del elemento al que estás clicleando. Es un poco difícil de programarlo por aquí y depende mucho de la estructura que tienes. QUIERO SUPONER que la estructura que tienes es así <div padre><div contenido> <div equis></div></div></div> y lo que quieres quitar es el div padre dandole clic al div equis. pues $(this) = div equis, entonces tienes que ir al padre de este: $(this).parent().remove();

Comment: si es algo asi lo que pienso tambien, seguire buscando para eliminar solo a uno porque el que comente  eliminas todos sus hijos enves de 1solo